# Storing user and shipping addresses

Tags: php

So on my checkout page when I push final checkout I want to store my users address and shipping address into a database. I am wondering if this could be shorter. Currently, users have multiple options:

1. Logged in where they use same or other shipping address.
2. Not logged in and they want to create account with same or different shipping address.
3. Not logged in where they create a guest account again with same or different address.

I know I can put my `$_POST` values direct in the `$createlines` but its just for making it clear now as I am still coding it.

Just wondering if theres some sort of function to get all values and fields from my database.

```
if (isset($_POST['final_checkout'])) {
$createuser = new User();
$createaddress = new Address();
$createshipping = new Shipping_address();




   if (!empty($logged_in)) {
        /*als same addres is aangevinkt bij ingelogde user*/
        if ($_POST['shipping'] == 'same' ) {

            $oldaddress = trim($_POST['oldaddress']);
            $oldcity = trim($_POST['oldcity']);
            $oldpostal = trim($_POST['oldpostal']);
            $oldcountry = trim($_POST['oldcountry']);

            $createshipping->user_id = $logged_in->id;
            $createshipping->address = $oldaddress;
            $createshipping->city = $oldcity;
            $createshipping->postal = $oldpostal;
            $createshipping->country = $oldcountry; //in tabel addresses nog kolom country maken en dan inputfield ook readonly stap 1

        /*als different adres is aangevinkt bij ingelogde user*/
        } else{

            $othershippingaddress = trim($_POST['create_otheraddress']);
            $othershippingcity = trim($_POST['create_othercity']);
            $othershippingpostal = trim($_POST['create_otherpostal']);
            $othershippingcountry = trim($_POST['create_othercountry']);
            $createshipping->user_id = $logged_in->id;
            $createshipping->address = $othershippingaddress;
            $createshipping->city = $othershippingcity;
            $createshipping->postal = $othershippingpostal;
            $createshipping->country = $othershippingcountry;
        }/*end else shippingaddress*/
    /*if user is !logged in*/
    }else{
        /*create account*/
        if ($_POST['optradio'] == 'create') {
            /*variabelen maken van de post*/
            $newusername = trim($_POST['create_username']);
            $newpassword = trim($_POST['create_password']);
            $newfirst = trim($_POST['create_first']);
            $newlast = trim($_POST['create_last']);
            $newmail = trim($_POST['create_mail']);
            $newaddress = trim($_POST['create_address']);
            $newcity = trim($_POST['create_city']);
            $newpostal = trim($_POST['create_postal']);
            $newcountry = trim($_POST['create_country']);
            /*usertabel invullen*/
            $createuser->username = $newusername;
            $createuser->first_name = $newfirst;
            $createuser->last_name = $newlast;
            $createuser->password = $newpassword;
            $createuser->user_mail = $newmail;
            $createuser->user_image = 'guest';
            $createuser->role_id = '4';
            /*adresses tabel invullen*/
            $createaddress->address = $newaddress;
            $createaddress->postal = $newpostal;
            $createaddress->city = $newcity;
            $createaddress->country = $newcountry;
            $createaddress->user_id = '';

            /*shipping adres same or different in de create account*/
            if ($_POST['shipping'] == 'same') {
                /*als same addres is aangevinkt bij nieuwe user*/
                $oldaddress = $newaddress;
                $oldcity = $newcity;
                $oldpostal = $newpostal;
                $oldcountry = $newcountry;
                /*shipping addres invoeren*/
                $createshipping->user_id = $createuser->id;
                $createshipping->address = $oldaddress;
                $createshipping->city = $oldcity;
                $createshipping->postal = $oldpostal;
                $createshipping->country = $oldcountry; //in tabel addresses nog kolom country maken en dan inputfield ook readonly stap 1


            } else{
                /*als different adres is aangevinkt bij nieuwe user*/
                $othershippingaddress = trim($_POST['create_otheraddress']);
                $othershippingcity = trim($_POST['create_othercity']);
                $othershippingpostal = trim($_POST['create_otherpostal']);
                $othershippingcountry = trim($_POST['create_othercountry']);
                /*shipping addres invoeren*/
                $createshipping->user_id = $logged_in->id;
                $createshipping->address = $othershippingaddress;
                $createshipping->city = $othershippingcity;
                $createshipping->postal = $othershippingpostal;
                $createshipping->country = $othershippingcountry;
            }/*end else different addres*/
        }else{
            /*als guestaccount is aangevinkt*/
            $guestnumber = User::number_guest();
            $newusername = 'guest' . $guestnumber;
            $newpassword = '';
            $newfirst = trim($_POST['create_first']);
            $newlast = trim($_POST['create_last']);
            $newmail = trim($_POST['create_mail']);
            $newaddress = trim($_POST['create_address']);
            $newcity = trim($_POST['create_city']);
            $newpostal = trim($_POST['create_postal']);
            $newcountry = trim($_POST['create_country']);

            /*usertabel invullen*/
            $createuser->username = $newusername;
            $createuser->first_name = $newfirst;
            $createuser->last_name = $newlast;
            $createuser->password = $newpassword;
            $createuser->user_mail = $newmail;
            $createuser->user_image = 'guest';
            $createuser->role_id = '4';
            /*hier al saven om id te krijgen*/
            /*adresses tabel invullen*/
            $createaddress->address = $newaddress;
            $createaddress->postal = $newpostal;
            $createaddress->city = $newcity;
            $createaddress->country = $newcountry;
            $createaddress->user_id = '';


            if ($_POST['shipping'] == 'same') {
                /*als same addres is aangevinkt bij guest*/
                $oldaddress = $newaddress;
                $oldcity = $newcity;
                $oldpostal = $newpostal;
                $oldcountry = $newcountry;
                /*shipping addres invoeren*/
                $createshipping->user_id = $createuser->id;
                $createshipping->address = $oldaddress;
                $createshipping->city = $oldcity;
                $createshipping->postal = $oldpostal;
                $createshipping->country = $oldcountry; //in tabel addresses nog kolom country maken en dan inputfield ook readonly stap 1


            } else{
                /*als different adres is aangevinkt bij guest*/
                $othershippingaddress = trim($_POST['create_otheraddress']);
                $othershippingcity = trim($_POST['create_othercity']);
                $othershippingpostal = trim($_POST['create_otherpostal']);
                $othershippingcountry = trim($_POST['create_othercountry']);
                /*shipping addres invoeren*/
                $createshipping->user_id = $createuser->id;
                $createshipping->address = $othershippingaddress;
                $createshipping->city = $othershippingcity;
                $createshipping->postal = $othershippingpostal;
                $createshipping->country = $othershippingcountry;
            }/*end elseif (guestaccount ->sameaddres)*/
        }/*end else (guestaccount)*/




    } /*end else (!logged in)*/
}/*end isset post*/
```

Comment: Your code indentation seems to be unbalanced (starting here: `if (!empty($logged_in)){`), can you fix that please.

Comment: just checked but indention seems ok to me the if ´(!empty($logged_in)){` is the start and everything is supposed to be in it or what u want me to do exactly

Comment: reformatted with the help of php storm so should be good no thx for reply tho

Comment: There's still a hanging `}` as you can see. That should be aligned with the code formatted section. It's either one too much from a missing opening brace, or you missed the code balance correctly.

Comment: hope its ok now sorry to bother u

Comment: The `}` still hangs off there.

Comment: is there a way i can send u my php file so u can see in ur editor its not hanging off? when i debug using Xdebug everything works i just wanted to know if theres a way to shorten it out

Comment: youre probably right im goin to rewrite the lot off it and then repost sorry

Comment: I am just referring how your code posted renders here, you can blatantly see that `}` isn't rendered in the code section. Fix that.

Comment: Hint `if ($_POST['sameaddress'] == '1' || 'on') {` also lags indentation now.

Comment: u are def right just checked and i ave one to many at the bottom gonna fix it thx

Comment: You should implement methods to set a bulk of properties for the various instances you're populating.

Comment: the indentation should be ok now as you will see i'm not yet including any save() its just written and testing out if i get all values i desire but just want to know how to write this shorter if it is possible

Answer (score 1):

In a sutuation when a block of code is present in both branches of an `if` statement, you can move this common part out of this statement. 
for example,

```
if (some condition) {
    $a = $x;
    $b = $y;
    $a = $z;
} else {
    $a = $x;
    $b = $y;
    $a = null;
}
```

it can be rewritten to

```
$a = $x;
$b = $y;
if (some condition) {
    $a = $z;
} else {
    $a = null;
}
```